# Configure WCF host servce

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, host

I have a basic question regarding the configuration of the Host app.config file

Let's say I host my WCF service on pc that its IP is: 123.456.789.001:9999

This is my app.config file:

```
<configuration>
```

```
<services>
  <service name="Service.WebexClient" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors"   >
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://<What should I put here>:9999/MyWebexService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>

</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/> 
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  httpGetUrl="http://<And What should I put here>:9999/MyWebexService/Help"/>

</behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I would like to know what are the right parameters I should insert in the baseAddress and in the httpGetUrl. I am confused. Should I put there "localhost" or the ip (123.456.789.001)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'd use the IP address for the endpoint and the WSDL for the httpGetUrl:

```
<baseAddresses>         
  <add baseAddress="http://123.456.789.001:9999/MyWebexService"/>
</baseAddresses> 

<behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >         
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>     
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://123.456.789.001:9999/MyWebexService?wsdl"/>        
</behavior>
```

Comment: I dont this is correct to do that:http://123.456.789.001:9999/MyWebexService?wsdl                                                Q: Calling ServiceHost.Open() on my queued application throws the following exception: System.ArgumentException: A base address cannot contain a URI query string. Why?

A: Check the queue URI in your configuration file and in your code. While MSMQ queues support the use of the '?' character, URIs interpret this character as the beginning of a string query. To avoid this issue, use queue names that do not contain '?' characters.

Comment: First question - are you using the MsmqBinding?  If you are, why are you using http: as the protocol for the address?

Comment: Then what I put above should work - the comment you posted appears to be specific to NetMsmqBinding.   Have you tried it my answer?  If it didn't work, did it give you any errors?